The painter I hired sanded exterior lead paint with a power sander and brushed with a wire brush. What do I do?
I own a 100year old house. Did not test for lead, but assuming it has lead paint. I cannot afford to hire a lead certified painter. So I hired a painter to paint the exterior of the house after I got good references and he has been painting over decades. He mentioned he did have experience painting old homes, so I hired him as he is within my affordability.
For the prep he covered all the windows with plastic and tape, he laid a drop cloth upto 4’ feet from the wall. He hand scrapped the loose paint and then power sanded the surface ‍♂️, me or my family (wife and 2yr old kid) are not at home while this was happening. I came home and saw them power sand and use a wire brush to dust and then prime, and by then they did that to one side of the (2story) house.
I asked them to stop immediately and told them that they cannot sand anymore, only hand scrape.
They collected the drop cloth with the chips (about 80/90%) and emptied them into their bin to dispose. However I saw paint chips spilled all along the foundation wall and very sparsely in some area in the yard(within 8ft) . After they left, I HEPA vacuumed the whole yard twice and picked as many chips as I could and watered the surface to reduce resurfacing. I still see paint chips in hard to reach areas.
I wet wiped my porch,stairs and outside high touch areas with swiffer. I also wet wiped inside close to the entry door.
My biggest worry is the well being of my child. He stays at the childcare center while the painters are working. But comes back home at 5:30/6pm.
I told the painters if they want to continue the work, they have to

not sand anymore and no wire brush,
only scrape the paint,
put a 6mil plastic below upto 10ft away from the house where possible and tape to avoid spilling. Clear it at the end of the day.
I am going to give them a hepa vacuum to clear dust to substitute for wire brush.

Did I do reasonable things? What else can I do?

As someone who also has lead paint and a hard time having it handled properly, I can sympathize, sorry to hear it. From research I've done it seems like hard scraping, generous drop cloth/plastic covering, and hepa vacuuming is a good strategy (along with PPEs for the workers and you during cleanup). Looking forward to hearing other's answers. Hope this goes smooth and is easy to move past for you.

Well, no veggie growing in the yard. Research vitamin D and decide for yourself if it’s worthwhile. Tape your windows closed from the inside while they’re working. Get blood tests in a few months.

@AloysiusDefenestrate: we were not at home while they were doing this. Still you think it is a good idea to get blood tests?
Also, thanks for the suggestion of taping windows from the inside.

Re: blood tests… personal choice. It could put your mind at ease or it could set you on a path for treatment.

Boy, worrying sure is a powerful emotion, isn't it?  I'm not a psychologist so I don't understand why people refuse to apply science to their problems.  Lead tests are readily available, go apply one to your chip/dust samples.  It's quite possible your painter did that before beginning.
